# Matlab dynamic table entries

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm writing a GUI with GUIDE

I wanted to create a table with dynamic features.
For example: I upload a matrix [n x i].
How can I tell Matlab to create i columns in my table?
This is the code I wrote:
I want to eliminate "Asset_1" & "Asset_2" and to put something that changes dynamically according to the initial matrix

```
function tabella_dati(handles)
Mdati=handles.matrici.Mdati;
%figura principale
form1=figure('Position', [400,300,600,400], 'Name', 'Tabella Dati', ...
    'NumberTitle', 'off', 'Color', [0.941 0.941 0.941], ...
    'Resize', 'off', 'WindowStyle', 'normal');
%______________________________statit text_________________________________
testo = uicontrol(form1, 'Style', 'text', 'Position', [250, 370, 100, 25], ...
    'String', 'Output');
%_________________________________Table____________________________________
[m n] = size(handles.array);
cnames = {'Asset_1','Asset_2', 'Returns', 'Sigmas', 'Quantile', 'Correlation', 'VaR'};
table = uitable('Data', Mdati, 'ColumnName', cnames,...
    'Parent', form1, 'Position', [10 50 580 320]);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion
**first**: define your data with length bigger than column*row
column =max(your column number) and row=max(your row number)
**second**: you must write for loop such as this one

```
h=row*column
for j=1:h
data(i)=c(i);
end
```

third:update your uitable data

```
set(handles.uitable,data,c);
```

i hope it will help you.